# Get partial stdout and stderr from Popen that runs indefinitely

Tags: python, subprocess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bypassing buffering of subprocess output with popen in C or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410849/bypassing-buffering-of-subprocess-output-with-popen-in-c-or-python)

I'm building a wrapper around a server cmd line script that should run indefinitely.
What I need to do is to get the current stout without waiting for the subprocess to finish.

I mean, if I run the following, everything works fine:

```
ls = Popen(["ls"], stdout=PIPE)
output = ls.stdout.read()
```

But if I do the same with an indefinitelly running program:

```
server = Popen(["python","-m","SimpleHTTPServer"], stdout=PIPE)
output = server.stdout.read()
```

It will not come back...

Update: Even

```
 output = server.stdout.read(1)
```

hangs...

Do you know if there's a way to capture partial output from a Popen (or similar threading implementation) in an OS independent way?

Comment: See the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410849/manipulating-pipe-buffer-size-in-c-or-python)

Comment: Is this cross platform? (it doesn't look like)

Comment: There is a description of the basic problem and a couple of solutions there.  If you can modify the running process to do flushes, that is best.  If you can't, Alex outlined the pexpect/wexpect trick which should cover both Unix-y and Windows platform.  If those don't work and you can't change the way the child process writes/flushes to stdout and stderr, you're likely out of luck.

Comment: @Santi: confirmed -- pexpect on all Unix variants inc. Mac, wexpect on Windows (if you're running on anything else there may or may not be a solution for other peculiar platforms).

Comment: Alright, I'll check those out to see if I'm lucky :)
Tks both.

Answer (score -1):

i would guess that read() returns the entire contents? If you read a fixed size chunk in a loop you may get better results.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that doesn't work either: server.stdout.read(1) hangs too.