# pipe not being read by subprocess?

Tags: c, linux, node.js, process, pipe

I want to run node.js as a subprocess and feed it input. Using C, here is some sample code of mine that does that.

The issue I have is that although the subprocess's stdout is still directed to the terminal, I see nothing after having fed the subprocess stdin a print 'Hello World' line. Even if I fflush() the pipe, I see nothing on output. However, if I close the pipe's input, then the 'Hello World' appears on the terminal.

The subprocess seems to simply buffer - why is that?
I would like to eventually redirect the subprocess stdout to another pipe and read it
in from main().

> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
>
> ```
>   int toNode[2];
>
>   pipe(toNode);
>
>   pid_t child_pid = fork();
>   if (child_pid == 0) { // child
>
>       // close write end
>       close(toNode[1]);
>       // connect read end to stdin
>       dup2(toNode[0], STDIN_FILENO);
>
>
>       // run node executable
>       char* arg_list[] = { "/usr/bin/node", NULL};
>       execvp(arg_list[0], arg_list);
>
>       fprintf(stderr, "process failed to start: %s\n", strerror(errno));
>       abort();
>    }
>    else { // parent
>
>       FILE* stream;
>
>       // close read end
>       close(toNode[0]);
>
>       // convert write fd to FILE object
>       stream = fdopen(toNode[1], "w");
>
>       fprintf(stream, "console.log('Hello World');\n");
>       fflush(stream);
>
>       //close(toNode[1]);
>
>
>       waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
>
>    }
>
> return 0;   }
> ```

Comment: Although [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410849/bypassing-buffering-of-subprocess-output-with-popen-in-c-or-python) refers to Python, it's the same underlying issue.  You must somehow convince the *other program* to do less buffering.  (I have no idea whether node.js can be told to do that, or if you need to resort to pseudo-ttys.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with the pipe being read. The problem is that `/usr/bin/node` only invokes the REPL (read-eval-print loop), by default, if it detects that `stdin` is interactive. If you have a sufficiently recent version of `nodejs`, then you can provide the `-i` or `--interactive` command line flag, but that will do more than just execute each line as it is read; it also really will act as a console, including inserting ANSI colour sequences into the output and printing the value of each expression.

See this [forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/n8_pCWqyuvk) for more information.