# How to get the current line from python's subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, sys

I am trying to accomplish a pseudo console with python's subprocess module for my web app.
The point of the webapp is to be able to run and interact with python code via the web.
I have a simple test.py script that has some sleeps and an input for testing purposes.

I am using `process = subprocess.Popen(['python', "-u",'test.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)` to run the file in a new subprocess.

I am retrieving the output lines like this:

```
for line in iter(process.stderr.readline, ''):
        #line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush the output buffer
```

Whenever my test.py python program gets to the input line, the print doesn't print the input line itself unless there is a newline character within the input prompt of test.py.

I was wondering if there is any way to get the output of the current line of the subprocess rather than only beeing able to access "processed" lines.

I also tried accessing stderr to no avail, I tried iterating over stdout.read until an empty char or a newline char was found, also to no avail.

Would love any help regarding this!

Comment: You’re… calling `readline`.  Is it supposed to return less than a line?

Comment: @DavisHerring Well no, it is just not the right function for what I am looking for. The documentation on the subprocess module is subpar at best. I am trying to get the current line the subprocess is on before it is processed, as I understand it this isn't accessible at all through stdout.

Comment: I think the documentation is assuming you know how interprocress communication works (for example, when should an “empty char” appear?).  There already are [questions about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410849/8586227), of course.

Comment: @DavisHerring I am very confused, bear with me pls. I have checked out the question you linked but didn't really get any wiser, since I am already using -u when calling the python subprocess. I guess I don't understand how the subprocess works. Are you able to explain to me where a python input text gets "sent" to before it's beeing processed?
If I run the python with the input in a regular cli it prints out the input text without issue, I just don't understand how to access it via the subprocess module

Comment: I didn't even notice that you were running with `-u`, sorry.  (Not all programs have such an option, so I was trying to address the general case.)  In that case, I simply [can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/39Q0GgAwDLxl9ChZ) your results; maybe you're calling `read()` (which reads until end of **file**, not just line) rather than `read(1)`?

Comment: @DavisHerring try adding a variable that gets assigned via input to slow.py

Comment: I’m not sure what that’s supposed to mean, but adding a variable assignment will certainly not change the semantics.  It’s true that this example just uses standard input, but that’s not a material difference versus the `subprocess` approach.